# Webform with multiple of the same membership

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm using webform 4.21 on Drupal 7.67 and CiviCRM 5.19.3 and I need to allow somebody to get a membership for multiple organizations.

1. By default there is one membership with 2 prices and the field is required
2. Additional memberships have only 1 price and I want to multiply, from 0 to XX extra memberships with a number field.

How to do I offer the second possibility?

regards,
Guillaume

[Webform's page](https://cnec.gestad.net/adhesion-CNEC)

[image]

[image: Membership tab in CiviCRM in Webform]

[image: Contribution tab in CiviCRM in Webform]

Comment: Hi Guillaume - please post some screenshots of your config (components) and your form (view)

Comment: Sorry I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to multiply/calculate Amounts based on webform fields, try webform_calculator module: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator

We've made some edits to support amounts being calculated over multiple pages - you can find what we're currently using for our projects here: https://github.com/KarinG/webform_calculator

**How it works**

The module adds a Formula webform component. So you can then configure a CiviCRM Contribution Amount or Membership Fee field to become a field of type Formula and specify the calculation with components.

Here's an example of a Processing Fee (which is a webform civicrm line item):
[image]

PS - I'm a bit confused though why you would want to buy multiple Memberships of the same type (in CiviCRM that would just mean multiple terms of one Membership Type) - but if you're looking to do Math the answer I've posted here using our latest webform_calculator module is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Karin! Thanks for your answer. I used in the meanwhile Webform calculation component module and apparently it does the job. I will try your solution in case of issues.

Comment: Hi Karin! I tried your improvement of the webform_calculator and it's awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Could it be possible that it doesn't support multipage?

Comment: Hi - it should support multipage - open another SE issue with details/specifics and I'll try and see if I can screenshot you an example there.